# Word for someone who joins a lot of contests

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

Is there a word for someone who joins a lot of contests?

- Like how this one castaway from Survivor pops up in The Amazing Race and now he's in Big Brother.
- This person was in American Idol 5 years ago, 2 years ago, in The Voice and now appears in X-Factor.

Comment: I can think of no such existing word or phrase, so I'm not providing this as an answer, but I might call such people *career reality-TV contestants*.

Comment: See "regular" -- also, there's a previous related post with the answer "regular."

Answer (score 1):

British English:

a **comper** *(informal)* - a person who regularly enters competitions in newspapers, magazines, etc, esp competitions offering consumer goods as prizes

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/comper

a **competition addict**, a serial comper:

https://www.theguardian.com/money/2018/jun/02/get-lucky-competition-addicts-raking-in-thousands-win-prizes